# on resizing jqgrid table header, header gets distorted

Tags: jqgrid, resize

I am facing issue on resizing the jqgrid headers. When i try to resize them, the headers dont match with the actual row data(as seen in the snap below).

I want the header rows to resize along with the data rows.
Please help.

I have uploaded the image on the following link: [Image-describing-shrink-issue](http://i46.tinypic.com/27xku8j.jpg)

Thanks,
AP

Answer (score 0):

1. For changing Column Header width in jqgrid use below code

   `$('.ui-jqgrid-labels > th:eq(2)').css('width','400px');`
2. For changing Column cells width in jqgrid use below code

   `$('#gridId tr').find("td:eq(2)").each(function(){$(this).css('width','400px');});`

[How to change header and column width in jqgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21930205/1624035) code example.