# Can I change column width in cellattr in jqgrid?

Tags: jqgrid

Can I change column width in cellattr? I tried this:

```
cellattr: function(rowId, value, rowObject, colModel, arrData) {
        return ' style= width: 100% !important; ';
    }
```

But there were no change. I didn't put width in colModel and put width in cellattr, it seems that the grid has max width for default so the texts inside the column is cutted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cellattr` can be used to specify attributes of **individual cells** (`<td>` elements) of the column. The **width of the column** is the common width of all cells. Nevertheless if you need to assign style attribute to all cells of the column you should use quotes in your code:

```js
cellattr: function () {
    return ' style="width: 100% !important;"';
}
```

If you would do this you will see that the `style="width: 100% !important;"` attribute will be assigned to all `<td>` elements of the column. I still not sure that it will follows to results which you expect.

Comment: thank you for the comment. I want to change the width of all cells of the column. So, I set width:100% in cellattr but some of texts still are hidden under the next column. Here is colModel definition: {name:'name', index:'name', cellattr: function(rowId, value, rowObject, colModel, arrData) { return ' style= width: 100% !important; '; }}. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In `th:eq(2)` here **2** indicates the `destination column` to increase column `header / cell` width. `eq` comparison starts from `0`. Here I mentioned third column(2) for increasing width of header and cell.

1. For changing `Column Header` width in `jqgrid` use below one

   **$('.ui-jqgrid-labels > th:eq(2)').css('width','400px')**
2. For changing `Column cells` width in `jqgrid` use below one

   **$('#gridId
   tr').find("td:eq(2)").each(function(){$(this).css('width','400px');})**

**Complete Example:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            //jqGrid
            $("#usersList").jqGrid({
                url:'<%=request.getContextPath() %>/Admin/getUsersList',
                datatype: "json",               
                colNames:['Edit','Primary Email','Active','First Name','Middle Name','LastName','Mobile Number'],
                colModel:[
                    {name:'userId',search:false,index:'userId',width:30,sortable: false,formatter: editLink},                       
                    {name:'email',index:'user.primaryEmail',width:150},
                    {name:'isActive',index:'user.isActive',width:80},
                    {name:'firstName',index:'firstName', width:100},
                    {name:'middleName',index:'middleName', width:100},
                    {name:'lastName',index:'lastName', width:100},
                    {name:'mobileNo',index:'user.mobileNo', width:100},
                    ],
                    rowNum:20,
                    rowList:[10,20,30,40,50],
                    rownumbers: true,  
                    pager: '#pagerDiv',
                    sortname: 'user.primaryEmail',  
                    viewrecords: true,  
                    sortorder: "asc",

            });
            $('#gridContainer div:not(.ui-jqgrid-titlebar)').width("100%");
            $('.ui-jqgrid-bdiv').css('height', window.innerHeight * .65);
            $('#load_usersList').width("130");
            $("#usersList").jqGrid('navGrid','#pagerDiv',{edit:false,add:false,del:false},{},{},{}, {closeAfterSearch:true});
            $(".inline").colorbox({inline:true, width:"20%"});

            $('.ui-jqgrid-labels > th:eq(2)').css('width','400px');
            $('#usersList tr').find("td:eq(2)").each(function(){$(this).css('width','400px');});
        });

        function editLink(cellValue, options, rowdata, action)
        {
            return "<a href='<%=request.getContextPath()%>/Admin/editUser/" + rowdata.userId + "' class='ui-icon ui-icon-pencil' ></a>";
        }
```